# Dúvida quanto ao uso de vários user control na mesma página

Tags: c#, asp.net

O mais difícil aqui é formular a pergunta do modo certo para não receber downvote, mas vamos lá. Tentarei explicar bem, pois a dúvida é complexa ou chata. Vou fazer perguntas pontuais para evitar perguntas com várias respostas. Aí vai.
Tenho 3 user control, mas minha aplicação só usa um ee preciso dos demais. Fui ver o código do formulário principal e o colega registrou o mesmo uc 3 vezes. Veja parte do código de como ficou.

```
Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Core.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback="true" CodeBehind="frmCadastroBens.aspx.cs" Inherits="Scania.SOMC.Web.frmCadastroBens" %>
<%@ Register src="WUC/wucCadastroBens.ascx" tagname="wucCadastroBens" tagprefix="uc1" %>
<%@ Register src="WUC/wucCadastroBens.ascx" tagname="wucCadastroBens" tagprefix="uc2" %>
<%@ Register src="WUC/wucCadastroBens.ascx" tagname="wucCadastroBens" tagprefix="uc3" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" runat="server">
    <link href="css/cadastroBens.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    <!-- INICIO - Campos Hidden para controle -->
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfCdProcesso" runat="server" Value="0" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfSomenteLeitura" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfNmUsuario" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfCdUsuario" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfAdministrador" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfCdTipoProcesso" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfWucChamador" runat="server" />
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hdfPreencheDocumentoCadFornecedor" runat="server" />
    <!-- FIM - Campos Hidden para controle -->

    <h2>Bens em aquisição / garantia</h2>    
    <br />
    <uc1:wucCadastroBens ID="wucCadastroBensNovoPV" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <uc2:wucCadastroBens ID="wucCadastroBensUsadosPV" runat="server" />
    <br />
    <uc3:wucCadastroBens ID="wucCadastroConfissaoDividaPV" runat="server" />
    <br />
```

Desta forma não consigo, por exemplo, usar o wucBensUsados, somente o wucBensNovos. A pergunta é: Devo registrar também o wucBensUsados? Esse é o procedimento correto?

Comment: Da uma olhada na atualização da minha resposta.

Answer (score 2):

Sim, para poder utilizar na pagina você deve registrar o controle.

Tem um modo mais fácil de fazer isso do que ir de página em página, basta registrar no web.config, como por exemplo

```
configuration>
  <system.web>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="uc1" src="WUC/wucCadastroBens.ascx" tagName="wucCadastroBens"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
```

E no seu caso, você registrou o mesmo user control 3 vezes, creio que esse seja o problema.

```
<%@ Register src="WUC/wucCadastroBens.ascx" tagname="wucCadastroBens" tagprefix="uc1" %>
<%@ Register src="WUC/wucCadastroBens.ascx" tagname="wucCadastroBens" tagprefix="uc2" %>
<%@ Register src="WUC/wucCadastroBens.ascx" tagname="wucCadastroBens" tagprefix="uc3" %>
```

Comment: O meu problema é com os demais uc. Tenho um wucBensUsados, que eu registrei no frmCadastroBens.aspx e não consigo trabalhar com ele. Nesse wuc eu tenho um HiddenField que eu não consigo atribuir valor a ele. Dá erro de como se ele não existisse. E por essa razão não consigo atribuir nada a nenhum campo em meu wucBensUsados, apenas no wucBensNovos.

Comment: Ao menos eu nao vi voce registrar esse UC na pagina que colocou o código aqui.

Comment: Desculpe-me, é assim que está no original. Eu fiz um registro, removendo o segundo registro e substituindo pelo novo uc e não deu certo.